# Logback increasing index format in Time and Size base archiving

Tags: logback

For my logback configuration I need to change the format of the increasing index in Time and Size base archiving "%i":

```
<appender name="FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIRECTORY}/myApp.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${ARCHIVED_LOG_DIRECTORY}/myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY_DAYS}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

In the logback documentation, it is said that each time the current log file reaches maxFileSize before the current time period ends,it will be archived with the increasing index token "%i", starting at 0.

In my case I need that this token starts from 01 and will be written on two numbers format (01, 02, 03,...)

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to control the increasing index pattern. We let the default behavior in the project.